# Webapp inside facebook-canvas: Get access token synchronous

Tags: facebook-canvas

I am having a webapp, a simple game, let's call it "some-game". This game is running standalone via http://www.some-game.com, and I have it running in a facebook-canvas https://apps.facebook.com/somegame-app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/canvas-tutorial, section "Authentication", describes, how to login the user when my webapp is loaded within the canvas. This is done asynchronously. So, some-game is loaded "logged-out", facebook-js-sdk works after some-game is loaded within the canvas, and I have access to the access-token and can log the user in. As it seems it is supposed to do this only by rebuilding the site using JavaScript.

I am hoping for an easier way to do this.

Is there any way to get the fb-access-token when some-game is loaded within the canvas iframe? My intention is to get this fb-access-token when initially loading some-game within the canvas, so I can send the "logged-in" version in the first place.